# Why my graphql queries throwing an error instead of response?

Tags: node.js, api, graphql, graphql-js

I'm working on `graphql-yoga/node` at the moment.

I've got an index.js file like below:

```
import { createServer } from "@graphql-yoga/node";
import { readFileSync } from "node:fs";
import Comment from "./resolvers/Comment";
import Query from "./resolvers/Query";
import Post from "./resolvers/Post";
import User from "./resolvers/User";
import Mutation from "./resolvers/Mutation";
import db from "./db";

const typeDefs = readFileSync("./src/schema.graphql", "utf-8");

const server = createServer({
   schema: {
    typeDefs,
    resolvers: { Query, Mutation, Post, User, Comment },
    context: { db },
  },
});

server.start();
```

I have a separate files for schema and resolvers.

Schema file is as follows:

```
type Query {
  posts(query: String): [Post!]!
  users(query: String): [User!]!
  comments(query: String): [Comment!]!
}
type Post {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  body: String!
  isPublished: Boolean!
  author: User!
  comments: [Comment!]!
}
```

Resolver is as follow:

```
const Post = {
  author(parent, args, { db }, info) {
    return db.users.find((user) => {
      return user.id === parent.author;
    });
  },
  comments(parent, args, { db }, info) {
    return db.comments.filter((comment) => {
      return comment.post === parent.id;
    });
  },
};

export { Post as default}
```

I have a separate Query file

```
const Query = {
posts(parent, args, { db }, info) {
    if (!args.query) {
      return db.posts;
    }

    return db.posts.filter((post) => {
      const isTitleMatch = post.title.toLowerCase().includes(args.query.toLowerCase());
      const isBodyMatch = post.body.toLowerCase().includes(args.query.toLowerCase());
      return isTitleMatch || isBodyMatch;
    });
  }
}
export { Query as default };
```

db is the file where static data is saved.

```
const posts = [
  {
    id: "4",
    title: "The alchemist",
    body: "There is only one thing that makes a dream impossible to achieve: the fear of failure.",
    isPublished: true,
    author: "1",
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    title: "Dear stranger",
    body: "the truth is you are at war with yourself thats why you find yourself at war with others.",
    isPublished: false,
    author: "3",
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    title: "Warren buffet",
    body: "The most important thing to do if you find yourself in a hole is to stop digging.",
    isPublished: true,
    author: "3",
  },
];
```

There are no errors in the console. Everything appears to be in good working order. However, when I try to run the post query as described below, I get an error rather than a response.

```
query {
  posts {
    id
    title
    body
  }
}
```

the Error:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Unexpected error.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "posts"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're getting an error on the server side. Could you share your terminal/logs output?

Also, the `context` option should be at the root level, not under `schema.`
Could you try the following?

```js
const server = createServer({
   schema: {
    typeDefs,
    resolvers: { Query, Mutation, Post, User, Comment },
   },
   context: { db },
});
```